# readline confused by ANSI escape sequences

Tags: python, bash, ansi-escape

I'm working on a Python script which at times requires input to be typed in by a user. I'm using bash on macOS Sierra.

To receive the input, I wrote the following:

```
import readline  # gnureadline 6.3.8

START = '\033[91m\033[1m'
END = '\033[0m'

response = raw_input(START + 'Enter text: ' + END)
```

I am using the the ANSI escape sequences in `START` and `END` to visually differentiate the script's prompt from the user's text entry.

Unfortunately, once I start typing in the text, the program loses track of where the beginning of the user-inputted text actually is. The first carat below is where <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> now maps to, and the second is where <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> takes me. The arrow keys similarly believe the beginning and end of the user input are offset as shown.

```
Enter text: hello my name is             
                         ^               ^
```

I tried a few things to debug this.

1. I tried putting a newline between the prompt and the text entry, but that only made the offset worse.
2. If I *only* use the arrow keys and never things like <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, option-arrow to navigate through the string, this works as expected. That said, given the length and complexity of the strings the user is entering, using only the arrow keys to move through the string will be painful for the user.
3. Most significantly, if I don't use `START` and `END` at all, this works perfectly. That said, the usability of the script drops -- it's hard to pick out the prompts from all the other text going by in the full version of this script.

Is there some trick for me to be able to use the ANSI escape sequences to format the prompt without messing up the user's ability to navigate using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, and option-arrow?

Comment: What if you `print(START + 'Enter text: ' + END, end='')` and then `response = raw_input()`? I’m not near an interpreter to try this, but just an idea.

Comment: Does Readline support the Bash `$PS1` style marking of non-printing sequences with `\[` and `\]`?  BTW, prefer to use `tput` for portable terminal codes - not every terminal is a VT220!

Comment: @ndmeiri The `end=''` syntax isn't working for me (Python 2.7.15), but separating the prompt and `raw_input` into two separate calls seems to do the trick (though it introduces a linebreak).  Thanks!

Comment: @TAH Oh nice. I'll expand and add that as an answer

Comment: `\[` and `\]` are prompt-specific, but they represent `\001` and `\002` that Readline itself uses in general (IIRC).

Comment: However, I think whether `Readline` is relevant depends on the environment in which you run the script. Python itself isn't using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate printing the prompt and asking for input into two commands.

**Python 3.x**

```
print(START + 'Enter text: ' + END, end='')
response = input()
```

**Python 2.x**

```
import sys

# Use sys.stdout.write to avoid printing a trailing newline.
sys.stdout.write(START + 'Enter text: ' + END)
response = raw_input()
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about avoiding the trailing newline!

Comment: You can suppress the newline with `print` in Python 2 by ending the statement with a comma: `print …,; response = raw_input()`.

Answer (score 4):

Readline expects `\001` and `\002` as markers around invisible characters:

```
import readline  # gnureadline 6.3.8

START = '\001\033[91m\033[1m\002'
END = '\001\033[0m\002'

response = raw_input(START + 'Enter text: ' + END)
```

With ANSI escape sequences prefixed with `\001` and suffixed with `\002`, GNU readline will know that these characters should be excluded when determining the length of the prompt string.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the accepted answer didn't worked out.

I started with

```
START = '\x1b[7m\x1b[37m' # white on black
END = '\x1b[0m'  # reset
response = input(START + 'QUERY ' + END)
```

Which similarly resulted in

```
QUERY hello my name is hello my name is
              ^                                ^
              hello my name is hello my name is
```

Using the solution above,

```
print(START + 'QUERY ' + END, end='')
response = input()
```

resulted in it considering the line to start at the beginning

```
QUERY hello my name is hello my name is
^                                ^
hello my name is hello my name is
```

probably due to the `input("")` being 0 characters long.

Knowing that those control characters get counted as offset, we can just use those to create an offset again.

My text, `QUERY`  is 6 characters long, so I could use

```
print(START + 'QUERY ' + END, end='')
response = input('\033[D\033[C')
```

Because [Cursor Forward, Cursor Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences)
`'\033', '[', 'D'`, `'\033', '[', 'C'`
is tricking `readline` to offset 6 characters.

```
QUERY hello my name is hello my name is
\[D\[C^                                ^
      hello my name is hello my name is
```